# Need to Allow Null or "" values for Dates - Access Query Data type mismatch

Tags: ms-access, vba

Basically I'm trying to use a Module or Public functions to pull a datediff that is only for business days. Everything works as far as the code is concerned but for some reason with a particular date field (one I've added after the database has been in production for some time) the code is not working correctly and I'm getting the "Data Type Mismatch in Expression". I'm 99% sure this is a data problem. If I compare two different dates it runs, I've created a test table with 10 records and it runs.

The field is set to  Date/Time. I guess my question is, is there anyway to get rid of the ""'s or make it so the code will accept these blanks as nulls? or convert them?

This is where I call the function in the query:

Exp1: BusinessDays([IntCallDate],[aIntCall1])

And here is the code in the module...

Thanks for any help - MUCH appreciated!!!

```
Public Function BusinessDays(dteStartDate As Date, dteEndDate As Date) As Long
On Error GoTo err_workingDays
    Dim lngYear As Long
    Dim lngEYear As Long
    Dim dteStart As Date, dteEnd As Date
    Dim dteCurr As Date
    Dim lngDay As Long
    Dim lngDiff As Long
    Dim lngACount As Long
    Dim dteLoop As Variant
    Dim blnHol As Boolean
    Dim dteHoliday() As Date
    Dim lngCount As Long, lngTotal As Long
    Dim lngThanks As Long
    If IsDate(dteStartDate) And IsDate(dteEndDate) Then 'added here begin
    dteStart = dteStartDate
    dteEnd = dteEndDate

    lngYear = DatePart("yyyy", dteStart)
    lngEYear = DatePart("yyyy", dteEnd)

    If lngYear <> lngEYear Then
        lngDiff = (((lngEYear - lngYear) + 1) * 7) - 1
        ReDim dteHoliday(lngDiff)
    Else
        ReDim dteHoliday(6)
    End If

    lngACount = -1

    For lngCount = lngYear To lngEYear
        lngACount = lngACount + 1
        'July Fourth
        dteHoliday(lngACount) = DateSerial(lngCount, 7, 4)

        lngACount = lngACount + 1
        'Christmas
        dteHoliday(lngACount) = DateSerial(lngCount, 12, 25)

        lngACount = lngACount + 1
        'New Years
        dteHoliday(lngACount) = DateSerial(lngCount, 1, 1)

        lngACount = lngACount + 1
        'Thanksgiving - 4th Thursday of November
        lngDay = 1
        lngThanks = 0
        Do
            If Weekday(DateSerial(lngCount, 11, lngDay)) = 5 Then
                lngThanks = lngThanks + 1
            End If
            lngDay = lngDay + 1
        Loop Until lngThanks = 4

        dteHoliday(lngACount) = DateSerial(lngCount, 11, lngDay)

        lngACount = lngACount + 1
        'Memorial Day - Last Monday of May
        lngDay = 31
        Do
            If Weekday(DateSerial(lngCount, 5, lngDay)) = 2 Then
                dteHoliday(lngACount) = DateSerial(lngCount, 5, lngDay)
            Else
                lngDay = lngDay - 1
            End If
        Loop Until dteHoliday(lngACount) >= DateSerial(lngCount, 5, 1)

        lngACount = lngACount + 1
        'Labor Day - First Monday of Septemeber
        lngDay = 1
        Do
            If Weekday(DateSerial(lngCount, 9, lngDay)) = 2 Then
                dteHoliday(lngACount) = DateSerial(lngCount, 9, lngDay)
            Else
                lngDay = lngDay + 1
            End If
        Loop Until dteHoliday(lngACount) >= DateSerial(lngCount, 9, 1)
        'MsgBox dteHoliday(5)

        lngACount = lngACount + 1
       'Easter
        lngDay = (((255 - 11 * (lngCount Mod 19)) - 21) Mod 30) + 21

        dteHoliday(lngACount) = DateSerial(lngCount, 3, 1) + lngDay + _
                (lngDay > 48) + 6 - ((lngCount + lngCount \ 4 + _
                lngDay + (lngDay > 48) + 1) Mod 7)
    Next


     For lngCount = 1 To DateDiff("d", dteStart, dteEnd)
        dteCurr = (dteStart + lngCount)
        If (Weekday(dteCurr) <> 1) And (Weekday(dteCurr) <> 7) Then
            blnHol = False
            For dteLoop = 0 To UBound(dteHoliday)
            'MsgBox dteHoliday(dteLoop) & "  " & dteLoop
                If (dteHoliday(dteLoop) = dteCurr) Then
                 blnHol = True
                End If
            Next dteLoop
            If blnHol = False Then
                lngTotal = lngTotal + 1
                'MsgBox dteCurr
            End If
        End If
    Next lngCount

BusinessDays = lngTotal
Else                'Add
BusinessDays = -1 ' add
End If   'add


err_workingDays:
MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
"Description: " & Err.Description
Resume exit_workingDays



End Function
```

Comment: More specifically - If i run the query and scroll down a bit, an error pops up "Subscript out of range" and highlights the line:

Answer (score 0):

The code fails when `Year(dteStartDate) > Year(dteEndDate)`

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Conner: I appreciate your reviewing of potential problems on StackOverflow.  I assure you, though, that I meant this as an answer.  The OP states in his question that he is "99% sure this is a data problem."  I was simply identifying the data that would cause the error.  I left it up to the OP to find the offending records and take whatever he felt was appropriate corrective action.

Comment: I hope my review didn't offend you. The review process is currently in beta and so it still needs some kinks worked out. One of those kinks is that reviewers are unable to view the full context of the question. Thus, I only have your question to look at. I assessed that this particular answer is rather short and could easily be made into a comment. I think SO is looking to incorporate answers that include more explanation that may benefit future users of less localized issues. I know this isn't always possible, but I just made a gut decision in a matter of seconds. Regards.

Comment: I figured as much.  No offense taken.  Speaking of context, it might help if there were some sort of [Review] tag associated with comments added as part of the Review process.  I was initially confused as to why there was sudden activity on such an old thread.  It made more sense when I saw the recent activity on your profile.  If you have any input on the review process (seeing as it is still in beta and you seem to be an active reviewer-Kudos!), you might consider passing along my suggestion.  Keep up the good work in helping to improve the SO community!

Answer (score 0):

You can't ReDim an array to a negative value.

When lngEYear < lngYear, lngDiff will be less than zero.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this line:

```
If IsDate(dteStartDate) And IsDate(dteEndDate) Then 'added here begin
```

is necessary, since you'll get Type Mismatch errors if you try to feed other types of values into the function. In any case, you also/instead should have something like:

```
If dteStartDate <= dteEndDate Then
```

with the Else portion returning a "known bad" answer, the way your code does here:

```
Else                'Add            
    BusinessDays = -1 ' add            
End If   'add
```

This is just an expansion of the answers already posted by Jim Anderson
 and mwolfe02
. If you accept this answer/vote it up, you should also vote up theirs....

Comment: Because the variables `dteStartDate` and `dteEndDate` are declared as type Date, the IsDate function will always return true.  However, passing a string to IsDate will not cause a type mismatch error.  Rather, if the string can be converted to a date, the function will return true; otherwise, it will return false.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a data type mismatch because you have declared the parameters as `Date` type.  While a `Date/Time` column in the database can hold a null value, a `Date` variable in VBA cannot.  You must therefore declare the parameters as `Variant`s, and do some type checking at the head of your function.

This means that my comment to another answer (saying that `IsDate` will always return true here) is misleading.  Rather than deleting the meaningless `IsDate` check, you should make the check meaningful by changing the parameter type from `Date` to `Variant`.

Hope this helps.